# X increase the font size of a single application (no X resources)

Tags: xorg, fonts

I want to increase the font size of a single X application which doesn't seem to have an Xresource for fonts and faces. How might I go about doing this?

(Ironically, the applications for which I want to increase the font size of are [editres](https://linux.die.net/man/1/editres) and [xfontsel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xfontsel). I'm using this to configure a high-resolution display.)

## Links and approaches tried

- [appres](https://linux.die.net/man/1/appres) can be used to list Xresources that can be set for an application. But the [output for editres](https://pastebin.com/raw/p8MXEjpB) [contains no mention of font or face](https://pastebin.com/0tgGQjjP)
- [Arch wiki discusses high resolution displays](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI)
- [Some applications have Xresources for font settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm#161704)
- [This question discusses scaling an X application](https://superuser.com/questions/950794/per-application-window-scaling-in-xorg-for-high-dpi-display#1189909). The approaches there don't apply to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those use the X toolkit (as noted in their manual pages), which means they also recognize its command-line options such as **`-fn`** (font).  In a quick check, I was able to run those with the 10x20 font.

```
editres -fn 10x20
xfontsel -fn 10x20
```

There is a summary of the options in [X(7)](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#sect12).

Comment: Nice. These seem to accept any x font (`xlsfonts`) including [scalable fonts](https://tronche.com/wiki/Howto_specify_X_scalable_fonts_from_the_command_line): `-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-normal--$PXSIZE-0-100-100-p-0-iso8859-1`